# Jquery data to Controller

Tags: jquery, symfony

I create jquery function in my tempalte

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var select = $('select').prop("selected", true).val();
            var checkbox = [];
            $('input:checked').each(function() {
                checkbox.push(this.name);
            });
            alert(checkbox);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('transportAction') }}",
                data: {'storage': select, 'product':checkbox},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.success == true)
                    {
                        alert("Ok");
                        window.location.replace("");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

In my controlle i create this

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('request');
        var_dump($data);
        die();
    }
```

In result var_dump give me null. What i do wrong?
P.S 
How parse checkbox array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case (`POST` request) a field `$request->request` is a `ParameterBag` object on which you can call `get` method. Argument to `get` method is a key of request param, so in your case you need to use `storage` or `product`

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $parameterBag = $request->request;
    $storage = $parameterBag->get('storage');
    $product = $parameterBag->get('product');
}
```

**EDIT:** you should also remove `'` from your keys in `data` attribute:

```
data: {storage: select, product:checkbox},
```

**EDIT2:** you are using `prop` method wrong. Check [doc](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) when it's meant to be used. In your case `$('select').val();` should be enough, however you should use more specific selector than just `select` because this one will select all `select` elements in your DOM

Comment: still null ( What could it be? Maybe wrong data in jquery transmitted data?

Comment: try to add some dummy data in jquery (like ``data: { dummyKey => 'dummyVal'}`` ) and check what is output of ``var_dump($parameterBag->get('dummyKey')``. Also try to remove ``'`` out of ``'select'`` and ``'product'``

Comment: i don't understand but it still null. I alert my data in template, it displayed all what i need

Comment: you can also check your ``$_POST`` superglobal variable. If parameters are there then your ajax sends data correctly

Comment: If i var_dump(($_POST['storage'])) i have error `Notice: Undefined index: storage`. Thats mean that my script send data with error?

Comment: yes. Try to remove ``'`` from ``'storage'`` (make it ``{storage: select, product: checkbox}`` and try to do ``var_dump($_POST)``

Comment: yes. you are right ) Thank you.
Can you tell me, how i can parse array in my controller('products')

Comment: ``$parameterBag->get('product')`` should be a regular php array. Please accept my answer

Comment: there is one problem: send only products but not storage